# Problems with quoting while using YQ in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, yaml, yq

I'm trying to run this yq command in PowerShell:

```
yq eval '.. | select(has(""CK_RUN_CASE""))' problemset.yml
```

but I get this error message:

```
Error: open .. | select(has("CK_RUN_CASE)) problemset.yml: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I was trying to follow this hint, but no success:
https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/tips-and-tricks#quotes-in-windows-powershell

It works on my Ubuntu machine with quotes like this:

```
yq eval '.. | select(has("CK_RUN_CASE"))' problemset.yml
```

but I really need it to work on my Windows machine for some reasons. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this test file:

```
# problemset.yml
CK_RUN_CASE: foo
array:
  - CK_RUN_CASE: bar
```

Triple quoting the key name in powershell seems to work :

```
$ yq eval '.. | select(has("""CK_RUN_CASE"""))' problemset.yml
CK_RUN_CASE: foo
array:
  - CK_RUN_CASE: bar
CK_RUN_CASE: bar
```

Same for escaping the double quotes :

```
$ yq eval '.. | select(has(\"CK_RUN_CASE\"))' problemset.yml
CK_RUN_CASE: foo
array:
  - CK_RUN_CASE: bar
CK_RUN_CASE: bar
```

However, I can't find a syntax that works on both powershell and WSL/linux...

Comment: Tripple quoting works for me as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This had to have been one of the most frustrating debugging experiences I've had this year.  It wasn't until I tried to pipe yq output to jq that I got useful error messages.  Voicing this solution worked for me as well.